# Query Result: Where does "any" come from?

Tags: query, php

I created a simple custom object in salesforce.

There are 3 Extra fields: id, email, name (API Names: id__c, email__c, name__c)

I dumped 100 rows of random Mockup data into that object (some fields are empty)

There are no cennection, relationships, filters and other things. Just a plain table.

I created a query, which looks like... (There are no line breaks within the code, it should just give a better overview)

```
string(164) "SELECT 
                Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, Name, CreatedDate, 
                CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, 
                SystemModstamp, id__c, name__c, email__c 
             FROM 
                SimpleTestObject__c"
```

Now... it seems i got something wrong, because I didn't expecte the result to look like the following dump:

```
object(QueryResult)#22 (6) {
  ["queryLocator"]=>
  NULL
  ["done"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["records"]=>
  array(100) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#23 (3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(19) "MartinTestObject__c"
      ["Id"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(18) "a0426000001Kjd3AAC"
        [1]=>
        string(18) "a0426000001Kjd3AAC"
      }
      ["any"]=>
      string(502) "00524000000TsJlAAKfalse12015-10-07T15:49:09.000Z00524000000TsJlAAK2015-10-07T15:49:09.000Z00524000000TsJlAAK2015-10-07T15:49:09.000Z1Antonio Gordonagordon0@desdev.cn"
  }
  .... .... .... //100 times the same contents
}
```

Especially the "any" key got me there. Why is it just all data concatenated?

I expected it, to look a bit more like a SQL result... How to accomplish that?

Code for request is more or less a copy of the samples...

```
$this->connection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$this->client = $this->connection->createConnection("/path/to/salesforce.wsdl");
$this->login = $this->connection->login($this->login, decrypt($this->password).(($this->securityKey)?decrypt($this->securityKey):""));

$query = "SELECT ".implode(", ",$this->tableInfo["columns"])." FROM ".$this->tableInfo["table"];
debug::debugD($query); //dump of Query

$options = new QueryOptions(200);
$this->connection->setQueryOptions($options);

$response = $this->connection->query($query);

$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
!$done = false;
debug::Debugd($queryResult); //Dump of result
```

Comment: You need to update your WSDL (and possibly disable WSDL caching in PHP)

Comment: I generated a new partner.wsdl and added `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);` before initiation. The response didn't change in any way. May i missunderstood something, with the WSDL Cache?

Comment: For the partner api i think you need to wrap the resulting sobjects in something that decodes the any structure. see https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Query_Sample_(Partner)

Comment: Yes that solved it. Thanks. If you answer to the question, i will aproove it. It seems you have to go through the list as discribed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the response in a QueryResult object which'll do the work of decoding the any array for you. e.g.

```
  $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
  $queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
  for ($queryResult->rewind(); $queryResult->pointer < $queryResult->size; $queryResult->next()) {
    print_r($queryResult->current());
  }
```

See the [PHP Toolkit samples](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Query_Sample_(Partner)) for more info